# Multibinding ComboBox.Text

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, combobox

I have a combobox for selecting screen resolution width x height . For example :
1024x768 (Standard)
800x699 (Standard)
1500x900 (Wide)

I have a MutliValueConverter to convert the resolution string to a view model width and height member (in the ConvertBack method of the converter ) , but the Convert method just return null.

in the xaml for the combobox  I have

```
<ComboBox.Text>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource resolutionConverter}">
        <Binding Path="GameWidth"/>
        <Binding Path="GameHeight"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</ComboBox.Text>
```

When I click to select a value in the combobox , the combobox will fall back to selecting nothing . Why is that ?

Comment: not yet .. do you mean I don't need Multi value binding , and instead do my string to (width , height) conversion in the event handler when selection is changed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think you are supposed to do anything like that, normally you would just set the `ItemsSource` to your collection of viewmodels and the `DisplayMemberPath` to the name of the property which holds the display string and that should be about it. The selected item will then be the view model.

If the viewmodels have no display string you could bind to a dictionary of `<string,ViewModel>`, then you need to set the `DisplayMemberPath` to `Key` and the `SelectedValuePath` to `Value`, then the selected VM will be in the `SelectedValue` property.

(Another option to generate the displayed string for the items is using the `ItemTemplate`. the VM's should then of course have suitable properties which can be used in it. This will not work well together with `IsEditable` though)

Comment: SelectedItem can be any number of things like the value of an Enum (where ItemsSource is the enum values). I would probably make a ViewModel for the resolutions.

Comment: @RitchMelton: I was not speaking generally, i said it in the context of the preceding sentence where i suggested to set the ItemsSource to a collection of VMs. (Added a "then" to make that more clear...)

Comment: my combo box ItemSource is binded to a static List of strings ( of resolution names).  That list is not empty . My viewmodel has int width , height and I need those to be set when user select a string in the combobox .

Comment: @dan_l: As i said, do not bind to list of strings if you can bind directly to viewmodels, in your class replace the two properties by one: Resolution, and bind the selected item of the ComboBox directly to that property. That way the selected viewmodel becomes the resolution of the game.